# Symmetric subgraph configurations

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, symmetry, subgraph

Let $G,H$ be two simple graphs. Let's call a subgraph of $H$ that is isomorphic to $G$ a *$G$-subgraph*. Consider the following construction:

> **Construction:** Let $\mathcal G=\mathcal G(G,H)$ be a graph defined as follows
>
> - the vertices of $\mathcal G$ are the $G$-subgraphs of $H$.
> - two such $G$-subgraphs $G_1,G_2\subseteq H$ are connected by an edge in $\mathcal G$, if and only if there is no $G$-subgraphs in the union $G_1\cup G_2\subseteq H$ other than $G_1$ and $G_2$.

We might set $H=K_n$ for simplicity. At least this is the case I mostly dealt with.

> **Question:** For what graphs $G,H$ is $\mathcal G(G,H)$ highly symmetric, e.g. edge-transitive, or even [arc-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph)?

Note that it is not hard to make $\mathcal G(G,H)$ just vertex-transitive, e.g. $H=K_n$ already ensures this.

---

**Generalizations** (that might make it easier)

The question might be generalized as follows, and I would be still *very* interested in examples:
$G,H$ might be directed graphs, or multi graphs. This changes what is meant by beeing "isomorphic" to $G$.

---

**Some examples and further thoughts**

- Trivial cases include $G=H$ or when $G$ has not edges.
- Let $G$ be the $n$-cycle and $H=K_n$. This will give you a very complicated graph related to the edge-graph of the traveling-salesman-polytope. It is usually not edge-transitive.
- Consider Hamiltonian cycles in the cube, i.e. $G=C_8$ and $H=Q_3$. Then $\mathcal G$ is the octahedral graph, hence arc-transitive.
- Let $G$ be a the graph consisting of $k$ disjoint edges, and $H$ the graph consisting of $n\ge k$ disjoint edges. Then $\mathcal G$ is the [Johnson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph) $J(n,k)$, hence arc-transitive.
- I have the feeling that $G$ must be connected, very symmetric itself (e.g. arc-transitive), with a very symmetric complement (if $H=K_n$), und should use $\approx$ half of the edges of $H$. These are just feelings, nothing concrete here. I considered the Petersen graph in $H=K_{10}$, but this seems not to give edge-transitivity.

Comment: by union, you mean edge disjoint union, or, the join, i.e., the graph formed by making every vertex of one graph adjacent to every vertex of the other

Comment: $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both subgraphs of $H$, so by *union* I just mean throwing all the edges (and also vertices) of $G_1$ and $G_2$ into a single new subgraph of $H$. $G_1$ and $G_2$ might also not be edge-disjoint.

Comment: so union means the union of edge and vertex sets, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi Exactly.

Comment: isomorphism is an equivalence relation. Now, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are connected, and $G_1$ and $G_3$ are connected, then naturally, $G_1$ and $G_3$ must be connected , right.

Comment: @vidyarthi You mean connected by an edge or connected as graphs? The latter one *Yes*, the former one *No*, as we talk about subgraphs, not abstract graphs, and so isomorphic graphs might be embedded differently.

Comment: could you give a concrete example? let us consider $G=P_{10}$ and $H=K_{10}$, as you take. Now, could you give one connected component, or at least one vertex-edge pair for $\mathcal{G}(G,H)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96961/discussion-between-m-winter-and-vidyarthi).